# Why is the flash message stored in the session? Beacuse we are storing flash messages at req object and paasing to res.local in node js

Tags: node.js

I dont think flash message need to store at session beacuse they are stored in req and can paas in view via res.locals then why does need session?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why are we storing flashes in session?